how to force install.packages() access to https://cran-archive.r-project.org/windows/contrib/?
what I have:

what I want:
the install.packages function accessing to 'https://cran-archive.r-project.org/src/contrib/3.6/PACKAGES.rds'
Since my current system conditions only allow me to use R versions up to 3.6, I have to set the repo to the outdated version of the contib, but at the moment the install.packags function doesn't point to the correct URL in the “windows” folder, but rather to the “src” folder.

AFAIK, the CRAN archive is not a repository. I believe you will need to install packages from source. If any packages or their dependencies need R version  > 3.6, you  can try devtools::install_version to install an archived version that supported R 3.6. This will be a huge headache. R 3.6 is very old and you really should update.

You can't set the archive as a repository, because the archive isn't set up as one.  It would need to have various index files and they aren't there.
What you could do is to set up your own repository.  If you know the packages you will want, this is fairly easy.  The drat and miniCRAN packages help with this.
If you don't already know which ones you want, it will be harder.  You would need to search the archive to find the packages that claim to work in your version of R, then install those in your repository.  You should expect some errors, package authors don't always declare R version dependencies properly.
Overall, it's probably easier to work to change your "current system conditions" so that you can install a current release of R.
